# Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript

this my code

`index.ts`

```
import { isCTStr } from "./CT/isOCT";

let Avgo: string = "kamo";
let Pult: unknown = 15;
const x = (a: string) => {};

(function() {
  if (!isCTStr(Pult)) {
    return;
  }
x(Pult) // Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
})();
```

`./CT/isOCT`

```
const isCTStr = (value: unknown): boolean =>
  typeof value === "string" ? true : false;

export {isCTStr}
```

when i run the file index.ts i get error.

> Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a special return type to make isCTStr a [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
const isCTStr = (value: unknown): value is string =>
  typeof value === "string" ? true : false;
```

PS, the ternary is also unnecessary; you can get the same effect with:

```
const isCTStr = (value: unknown): value is string =>
  typeof value === "string";
```

Comment: Nicholas! I have a similar issue. I could not figure out. I event dont understand the issue. Can you please take a look if u have time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66364409/argument-of-type-unknown-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string-even?noredirect=1#comment117326917_66364409